# Netbeans - 'Build all dependencies' internal working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

Netbeans has an option to build all dependencies. I read it uses maven reactor plugin to achieve this. How does it achieve that.

Can it be achieved using maven through command-line.